# After using bitmap factory image width and height is increasing?

Tags: android

I have one image, image width is 290 and height is 330.when i used bitmap factory for convert into bitmap width and height is increasing.My code is,

```
          mILearnBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.capital_a_1);
         mILearnBitmap = mILearnBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
         mILearnPixelsArry = new int[mILearnBitmap.getWidth() * mILearnBitmap.getHeight()];
         mILearnBitmap.getPixels(mILearnPixelsArry, 0, mILearnBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,mILearnBitmap.getWidth(), mILearnBitmap.getHeight());
         Log.d("mILearnPixelsArry", "---" + mILearnPixelsArry.length);
     Log.d("Width", "---" + mILearnBitmap.getWidth());
     Log.d("Height", "---" + mILearnBitmap.getHeight());
```

After using this code width increased to 435 and height increased to 495.Please tell i made mistake some there please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please use this function to resize image

```
     public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

    int width = bm.getWidth();

    int height = bm.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map

    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // matrix.postRotate(90);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;

}
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh thanks for ur reply.Here newWidth and newHeight means actual size of image right

Comment: no this is new size whatever you want. means if you want to resize image to 500x300 then resize image newheight=500 , newwidth=300 ok ?

Comment: where i call this method , i mean before bitmapfactory or after.please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, int destinationWidth, int destinationHeight, boolean filter);